# ckeditor find in getdata

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ckeditor

Does anyone know how you can access the DOM from an HTML page you got from the ckeditors `getdata` function, using javascript?

For instance:

```
function Delete_ftv_from_text(mfv_id)
{
    var content=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    content.getelementbyid(mfv_id);
}
```

So rather then accessing the `document.getElementById` I want to get the element out of the text from ckeditor, in this case the div element with an id that I get into my function.

The code above of course doesn't function.

Comment: You could put it in a temporary, hidden, div. But you can also immediately access it in the CKEditor instance itself (I think).

Answer (score 3):

You can access the DOM directly from the containing page:

```
var el = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].document.$.getElementById(id);
// do what you want with el
```